# 404 error in test Runner Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, hudson, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar when I execute

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -htmlSuite "*iehta" "https:// 
 app.mysite.com" "C:\Docs\Selenium\SeleniumTestCases 
 \Site_Regression.html" "C:\Docs\Selenium\SeleniumTestCases 
 \results.html"
```

Selenium Functional Test Runner fires up fine, however in the top, 
 left frame for test suite, I get:

HTTP ERROR: 404 
 Not found 
 RequestURI=/selenium-server/tests/Site_Regression.html

When I look at the properties for that frame, I see this is the URL of 
 the page it is trying to get to:

> `http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/tests/Site_Regression.html.`

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Selenium RC has been deprecated several **years** ago. It is no longer being updated for latest browser changes.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am using the latest version of selenium server